# ItemsControl don't display my items

Tags: c#, wpf

I'm trying to work with ItemsControl and CompositeCollection to display different shapes in a canvas but having some problems with the binding. Right now I only see the text "(Collection)" in my Canvas so that made me think that I'm trying to display a collection.

I don't know if I'm having problem with my resources or if I'm just thinking wrong here (like trying to display a the whole collection instead of every item) but would be happy with some pointers.

If I change "ItemsControl.Resources" to "ItemsControl.ItemTemplate" it display the first item in the list and I can only use one DataTemplate so that isnt good.

The code look like this, XAML:

```
<Grid>
        <ItemsControl ItemsSource="{Binding GraphData}">
           <ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>
                    <ItemsPanelTemplate>
                        <Canvas />
                    </ItemsPanelTemplate>
           </ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>
           <ItemsControl.Resources>
                    <DataTemplate DataType="model:Axle">    
                        <Line X1="{Binding StartX}" X2="{Binding EndX}" Y1="{Binding StartY}" Y2="{Binding EndY}"  Stroke="Black" StrokeThickness="2"/>
                    </DataTemplate>
            </ItemsControl.Resources>
        </ItemsControl>
</Grid>
```

And in my ViewModel:

```
public class GraphViewModel : ViewModelBase
{
    public ObservableCollection<Axle> Axles { get; set; } 
    public CompositeCollection GraphData { get; set; }

    public GraphViewModel()
    {
        Axles = new ObservableCollection<Axle>();
        GraphData = new CompositeCollection { Axles };
        InitializeAxles();
    }

    private void InitializeAxles()
    {
        //X-axle
        Axles.Add(new Axle
        {
            StartX = 50,
            StartY = 530,
            EndX = 530,
            EndY = 530
        });
        //Y-axle
        Axles.Add(new Axle
        {
            StartX = 50,
            StartY = 0,
            EndX = 50,
            EndY = 530
        });
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

you must not add Collection directly to CompositeCollection, but you have to wrap it into CollectionContainer:

```
 GraphData = new CompositeCollection { 
     new CollectionContainer { Collection = Axles }
 };
```

Comment: Yes, because collection property is initially null, so you need to wrap the items in an explicit element as shown above that instantiates the collection.

Comment: Acutally this doesnt work, when I do this and use ItemControl.Resources I just get a small text instead (the whole namespace + classname). Happen  to know why?